# Searching a custom listview using an ArrayAdapter in Android

Tags: listview, search, filter, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom listview that has two TextViews and one ImageView in it. It uses a custom ArrayAdapter as it's adapter, and I wanted to add a search function to it. I've looked through every single tutorial I could find, with no luck. However with one tutorial I was able to search through a regular listview (not using a custom adapter), however this will not work for me because I need to show both TextViews and the ImageView. I only need to filter one of the TextViews though, so I don't see how much trouble it could be.

Anyway, here is the MainActivity:

```
public class ItemId extends Activity {

    // List view
    private ListView lv;

    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;


    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testo);

        Context ctx = getApplication();
        Resources res = ctx.getResources();

        String[] options = res.getStringArray(R.array.item_names);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        // Adding items to listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item_test, R.id.product_name, options);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                ItemId.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

And here is the custom adapter:

```
public class ItemIDAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

    public LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public String[] mStrings;
    public String[] mIds;
    public TypedArray mIcons;   
    public int mViewResourceId;

    public ItemIDAdapter(Context ctx, int viewResourceId,
            String[] strings, String[] ids, TypedArray icons) {
        super(ctx, viewResourceId, strings);

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        mStrings = strings;
        mIds = ids;
        mIcons = icons;       
        mViewResourceId = viewResourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mStrings.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mStrings[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_icon);
        iv.setImageDrawable(mIcons.getDrawable(position));

        TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_text);
        tv.setText(mStrings[position]);

        TextView tv1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemids);
        tv1.setText(mIds[position]);

        return convertView;
    }


}
```

Hopefully someone can help me, as this has been a very tedious challenge because I'm new to Android development, and I'm out of options. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

in your oncreate():

```
 inputSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
         inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

             @Override
             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                 // When user changed the Text
                 youradaptername.getFilter().filter(cs);   
             }

             @Override
             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                     int arg3) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
         });
```

and in your layout:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search.."
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>
```